# How to populate Selectlist using stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, selectlist

In my MVC application I am trying to retrieve data using a stored procedure, then display it in a dropdown.

Here is My controller action

```
public ActionResult Register(string id )
{ 
    RegistrationModel Student = new RegistrationModel();

        using (var db = new StudentEntities())
        {
            var SportResultList = GetListOfSport();
            var SportSelectList = new SelectList(SportResultList);
            ViewBag.SportList = SportSelectList;

    return View(Student);
}
```

Here is the Method to get the list using the stored procedure

```
        public static List<GetSportsResult> GetListOfSport()
                {
       using (var db = new StudentEntities())
          {
ObjectResult<GetSportsResult> SportResults = db.GetSportsByStudentIdAndSeason(11111, 1);
List<GetSportsResult> results = SportResults.ToList();

           return results;
          }

        }
```

The stored procedure returns a complex type called `GetSportsResults` but I don't now how to access its fields.

Currently this code will display the `GetSportsResults` 20 times which is the right amount of records I should be getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [the constructor for `SelectList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286.aspx) you can specify which fields are to be used for the text and for the value.  This is done by passing string values to the constructor.

For example, if your `GetSportsResult` object has a `.ID` property as its identifier and a `.Name` property as its display value, then your code would look like this:

```
var SportResultList = GetListOfSport();
var SportSelectList = new SelectList(SportResultList, "ID", "Name");
ViewBag.SportList = SportSelectList;
```

This would indicate to the `SelectList` object that `GetSportsResult.ID` should be the value for each item in the list, and `GetSportsResult.Name` should be the displayed text for each item in the list.

Without specifying these fields, currently the object tries to make a "best guess" of what to display.  It's probably doing this by calling `.ToString()` on each object by default.  And the default behavior of `.ToString()` on a non-primative type is to display the name of the type itself, which is why you're seeing the string `"GetSportsResult"` for each item.

Comment: Thanks, adding the parameters to that SelectList fixed it